# Xpages Layout Control - Node Image path

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I use Application Layout control (OneUI 3.0.2) with a few Application Links.

The image path is calculated because the images are saved in a separate image application.
The problem is that the Layout Control always add the path of the current application in front of the calculated link.

The only way i found was to calculate the absolute path (with `http://..`) to avoid this. But for me this is not a good solution, specially when you want to use a reverseproxy in front.

Answer (score 1):

The image path is relative to current database by default.

Add "**/.ibmxspres/domino/**" in front of your image path to make it relative to Domino server's data directory instead.

*Example:*

Application path: /apps/hr/hr.nsf

Image database path: /core/images.nsf

```xml
<xe:basicLeafNode
    ...
    image="/.ibmxspres/domino/core/images.nsf/yourImage.gif">
```

---

In case the image database is in same directory like your application database you can set image's path relative to current database path.
Navigate from application database path back to common directory with `/..` and then to your database.

```xml
<xe:basicLeafNode
    ...
    image="/../images.nsf/yourImage.gif">
```